# Trigonometry Identity (Proving)

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove this identity?

$$\frac{\cos 2\alpha+\cos 2\beta}{1+\cos 2(\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{\cos (\alpha-\beta)}{\cos (\alpha+\beta)}$$

I've tried solving from L.H.S and R.H.S. But failed. Anyone can guide me? Thanks.

Comment: Did you simplify the expression using the double angle formula for cosine and using the addition rule for cosine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum to product formula is
$$
\cos2\alpha+\cos2\beta=
2\cos\frac{2\alpha+2\beta}{2}\cos\frac{2\alpha-2\beta}{2}=
2\cos(\alpha+\beta)\cos(\alpha-\beta)
$$
Next
$$
\cos2(\alpha+\beta)=2\cos^2(\alpha+\beta)-1
$$